# Restore Error of NuGet Packages in AzureDevOps Build

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-devops

I created a WEB application in Visual Studio with .Net Core 3.0, the application ran successfully locally. I set up continuous delivery for Azure DevOps so that I can generate a web service pipeline and when trying to build Azure can't restore NuGet packages. I have no experience with the platform I am having difficulty resolving.

[Build error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T482h.jpg)

Comment: Please explain how you are “trying to build” and what happens in your question. Do not post images of your IDE.

Comment: @DourHighArch I'm trying to build a DevOps Pipeline to have a web service.

Comment: I've done enough of this to have a hazy idea of what to do -- based on your error message, have you checked to see if your build agent supports .NET Core 3.0?

Comment: @Slothario I asked a colleague of mine for help, and discovered the error.
Actually the problem is in the environment that DevOps automatically generates, it does not support .Net Core 3.0.
I changed the agent to Azure Pipelines and specified as windows-2019.

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the Agent Pool that was automatically generated. It does not support .Net Core 3.0.
I changed the agent to Azure Pipelines and specified it as windows-2019 and the problem was solved.